# Setting a default content type for a backbone collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

How would I setup a Backbone collection to always send a content type of "application/json" in all requests?

code I have tried:

```
myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  headers: {"Content-Type": 'application/json'},
  url: '/foo'
});
```

and:

```
myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  contentType: 'application/json',
  url: '/foo'
});
```

however on `fetch()` there is no content type being sent?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is overriding `Backbone.sync`

```
var _sync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    options.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type': 'application/json');
    };
    _sync.apply(Backbone, arguments);
}
```

Then if you want to define your `Content-Type` per-model, you could do this :

```
var _sync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    options.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
        var contentType = model.contentType || null;
        // var contentType = model.contentType || 'application/json'; // default to json
        if(contentType) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type': contentType);
        }
    };
    _sync.apply(Backbone, arguments);
}
```

Though, if you're looking for a way to tell your server to return JSON on `fetch()` calls, what you're really looking for is the `Accept` header.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it globally for all your Backbone models and collections then you could provide your own [`Backbone.ajax`](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-ajax) function:

> **ajax** `Backbone.ajax = function(request) { ... };`
>
> If you want to use a custom AJAX function, or your endpoint doesn't support the *jQuery.ajax* API and you need to tweak things, you can do so by setting `Backbone.ajax`.

Something like this:

```
Backbone.ajax = function(request) {
    request = _({ contentType: 'application/json' }).defaults(request);
    return Backbone.$.ajax.call(Backbone.$, request);
};
```

The [`_.defaults`](http://underscorejs.org/#defaults) call will make a copy of `request` with `contentType` always set to `'application/json'`, if you don't copy `request` you'll end up alter data that you don't necessarily own; altering `request` may be harmless but good habits are good habits.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this for a collection not globally?

Comment: You could override the [collection's `sync`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-sync) method to always force `options.contentType = 'application/json'`. The implementation would look pretty much the same as the `Backbone.ajax` above except that `sync` gets three arguments with the (optional) `options` as the third.

Comment: Interesting, ok. I find it bizarre Backbone lets you set the URL and stuff as an option, but not request options. thanks!

Comment: I'd guess that no one has needed it before. And if you look at the `Backbone.sync` source you'll see that Backbone will set `contentType: 'application/json'` for everything except (AFAIK) a GET request (unless you have `emulateHTTP` turned on).

Comment: @w-van-kuipers your edit was rejected because the syntax is [a valid form of using underscore they call "oop style"](http://underscorejs.org/#oop).

Comment: Thanks for getting to that before me @tutuDajuju, I have a strong preference for the `_(x).m()` style when using Underscore.